# Create a loop in order to create freehand ROIs

Tags: matlab, loops, binary, mask

I have the following code done whereby I import a frame from a film, convert to grayscale and draw by freehand the region of interest. I then use Chan-Vese region fill to get my region of interest and create a mask based on this. I can finally get the binary image I'm looking for which is called BW3 in the code. Now this is the silly part. How do I create a loop such that the code will run (load frames 1 to 58), present me with the grayscale image for frame 1, allow me to draw the region of interest and then create and save the final binary image BW3?
Regards,
J

```
    % Select Initial Image
for n = 5:87
frame = read(obj,n);


%Isolate the Blade
imggray = rgb2gray(frame);
h_im=imshow(imggray);

%Region of interest
% r = imrect(gca,[646,188,18,-648]);
% BW2 = createMask(r,h_im);

hROI = imfreehand(gca);
Position = getPosition(hROI);
BW2 = createMask(hROI);

%Get blade Binary

BW3 = activecontour(imggray, BW2, 1000, 'Chan-Vese');

% Fill Holes
BW3 = imfill(BW3, 'holes');

% Form masked image from input image and segmented image.
maskedImage = h_im;
maskedImage(~BW3) = 0;

%Save binary frame
filename = sprintf('C:..........\\binaryimage%d.png', n);
imwrite(BW3,filename,'png');
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a limited number of frames (ie up to 58) you could just use a for loop to accomplish this. In your code, you will have to change the initial image code so that it iterates up with the loop.

```
for counter=1:58
    frame=read(obj,counter); 
    imwrite(frame,strcat('frame',num2str(counter),'.png'))
    .....% the remainder of your code likely remains unchanged.
end
```

When writing your results, you would likely need to drop it into a struct of some sort so that you can loop through unless you write your results to a file in each loop.

Comment: Hi, I managed to do it myself. See amended code. For some reason I just lost myself for a bit and could not figure it out. Thanks again